# TimThumb error: Could not get a lock for writing

Tags: wordpress, nivo-slider, timthumb

I am using a nivo slider for a wordpress theme... just out of the blues the slider broke. You can see it here www.habitude.ca
When i copy the img url to the browser I get the following error.

---

A TimThumb error has occured

The following error(s) occured:
Could not get a lock for writing.

Query String : src=http://habitude.ca/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/rock_bottom1.jpg&h=316&w=980

### TimThumb version : 2.8

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

This error means some sort of directory permissions issue on the cache directory so make sure your php script can write to the cache directory.